# Problems with restoring SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have been working for hours now trying to figure out why I can't get my C# application to restore a SQL Server 2008 database.
I use the following code:

```
var conn = new SqlConnection("SERVER=Server;DATABASE=master;User ID=sa;Pwd=Password");
var srvConn = new ServerConnection(conn);
var srv = new Server(srvConn);

Restore res = new Restore();
res.Database = "RestoredDatabase";
res.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
res.Devices.AddDevice("Path to .bak-file", DeviceType.File);
res.ReplaceDatabase = false;
res.SqlRestore(srv);
```

When I run the code nothing happens. No errors or exceptions occurs! I have been looking around the web for a solution, but all examples are exactly the same, so no help there.

Could it be a problem with the connection, or maybe a problem with the .bak-file?

I'm surprised that there are no real debugging-features such as exceptions when using objects from Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.

Comment: Tried using SQL to restore it? What class is your Restore class? Namespace?

Comment: Try to use `ReplaceDatabase = true` - if the database is not there yet, it won't hurt anyway...

Comment: You might also want to check out: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/BackupRestoreWithSmo.aspx

Comment: And one more thing: is your *.bak file on a drive connected to your physical SQL Server?? You need to run your restore app on the machine that the database should be restored to, and the *.bak file must be available to the account running your app.

Comment: @marc_s: Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Restore.

Comment: I got the restoring to work. Partially. I can now overwrite the existing database and sort of rollback. But I can't create a new database from the backup.

Answer (score 1):

- First, try restoring the database using the management studio options, using the same authentication info and the same .BAK. If it don't works, the problem is not on your code.
- If the first experiment worked fine, and supossing the database is already created, make sure no one is connected to it before launching restore. You can execute the instruction sp_who2 in Sql Server to make sure there is no connections to that database.

Answer (score 1):

You can also roll your own code if you like.  I use this in some integration tests to restore databases to a clean state.  I reset the database to single user mode so if anyone is connected to it - it will kick them off so I can restore it.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("ALTER DATABASE ");
sb.Append(" [");
sb.Append(databasename);
sb.Append("] ");
sb.Append(" SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;");
sb.Append("RESTORE DATABASE ");
sb.Append(" [");
sb.Append(databasename);
sb.Append("] ");
sb.Append(@" FROM DISK = N'D:\SQLBACKUPS\AUTOMATION\");
sb.Append(backupfilename);
sb.Append("' WITH FILE=1, NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, STATS=10");
return sb.ToString();
```

Then just create a sql command object and pass in the results from the string builder as the command text and execute.

Answer (score 0):

This may be some permission Problems, due to which also sometimes the restore will not happen. Try taking restore of the ".bak" file first with your local databases which is accessible with your username and password. Any how visit the [Sql BackupRestore](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1849) site for more details about Sql Backup using C#.net. Hope it will help you.

Comment: I use the same namespace/classes to create the .bak-file with the same user/permissions. The application is not running on the same machine as the database, but the .bak-file is located on the "DB-machine".

Comment: After you have taken the Backup of a database, make sure that the Connection to Sql server through Sql Server Management studio is closed or not, if its not closed then also the code for restore will not work.